# Ошибка при инициализации OpenGL окна

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include "gl\GL.h"
#include "gl\GLU.h"
#include "gl\GLaux.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "OPENGL32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Glaux.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "GLU32.lib")

HGLRC hRC = NULL;
HDC hDC = NULL;
HWND hWnd = NULL;
HINSTANCE hInstance;

bool keys[256];
bool active = true;
bool fullscreen = true;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

GLvoid ReSizeGLScene(GLsizei width, GLsizei height)
{
    if(height == 0)
    {
        height = 1;
    }
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)width/(GLfloat)height, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

int InitGL(GLvoid)
{
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH); //  Плавное смешивание цветов
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Очистка экрана в черный цвет

// Создание буфера глубины
    glClearDepth(1.0f);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL);

    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);

    return true;
}

int DrawGLScene(GLvoid)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    return true;
}

GLvoid KillGLWindow(GLvoid)
{
    if(fullscreen)
    {
        ChangeDisplaySettings(NULL, 0);
        ShowCursor(true);
    }

    if(hRC)
    {
        if(!wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL))
        {
            MessageBox( NULL, 
                        _T("Не возможно уничтодить контексты RC и DC"),
                        _T("SHUTDOWN ERROR"),
                        MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }
        if(!wglDeleteContext(hRC))
        {
            MessageBox( NULL,
                        _T("Невозможно удалить контекст рендеринга"),
                        _T("SHUTDOWN ERROR"),
                        MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }
        hRC = NULL;
    }

    if(hDC && !ReleaseDC(hWnd, hDC))
    {
        MessageBox( NULL,
                    _T("Невозможно уничтодить контекст устройства"),
                    _T("SHUTDOWN ERROR"),
                    MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        hWnd = NULL;
    }
    if(!UnregisterClass(_T("OpenGL"), hInstance))
    {
        MessageBox( NULL, 
                    _T("Невозможно зарегистрировать класс"),
                    _T("SHUTDOWN ERROR"),
                    MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        hInstance = NULL;
    }
}

BOOL CreateGLWindow(LPCWSTR title, int width, int height, int bits, bool fullscreenflag)
{
    GLuint PixelFormat;
    WNDCLASS wc;

    DWORD dwExStyle;
    DWORD dwStyle;

    RECT WindowRect;
    WindowRect.left = (long)0;
    WindowRect.right = (long)width;
    WindowRect.top = (long)0;
    WindowRect.bottom = (long)height;
    fullscreen = fullscreenflag;

    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW|CS_OWNDC;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_WINLOGO);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName = _T("OpenGL");
    wc.lpszMenuName = NULL;

    if(!RegisterClass(&wc))
    {
        MessageBox( NULL, 
                    _T("Ошибка при регистрации класса окна"),
                    _T("ERROR"),
                    MB_OK|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return false;
    }

    if(fullscreen)
    {
        DEVMODE dmScreenSettings;
        memset(&dmScreenSettings, 0, sizeof(dmScreenSettings));
        dmScreenSettings.dmSize = sizeof(dmScreenSettings);
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsWidth = width;
        dmScreenSettings.dmPelsHeight = height;
        dmScreenSettings.dmBitsPerPel = bits;
        dmScreenSettings.dmFields = DM_BITSPERPEL | DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT;

        if(ChangeDisplaySettings(&dmScreenSettings, CDS_FULLSCREEN)!=DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
        {
            if(MessageBox(NULL,
                            _T("Не удалось выполнить установку настроек экрана. Выйти в оконный?"),
                            _T("Emel GL"),
                            MB_YESNO|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION)==IDYES)
            {
                fullscreen = false;
            }
            else {
                MessageBox(NULL, 
                            _T("Программа сейчас закроется"),
                            _T("ERROR"),
                            MB_OK|MB_ICONSTOP);
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    if(fullscreen)
    {
        dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
        dwStyle = WS_POPUP;
        ShowCursor(false);
    }
    else {
        dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW|WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE;
        dwStyle = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
    }
    
    AdjustWindowRectEx(&WindowRect, dwStyle,false, dwExStyle);

if( !( hWnd = CreateWindowEx(  dwExStyle,         
          _T("OpenGL"),         
          title,           
          WS_CLIPSIBLINGS |      
          WS_CLIPCHILDREN |      
          dwStyle,          
          0, 0,        
          WindowRect.right-WindowRect.left,   
          WindowRect.bottom-WindowRect.top,    
          NULL,           
          NULL,            
          hInstance,       
          NULL)))         
    {
        KillGLWindow();
        MessageBox(NULL, 
                    _T("Ошибка при создании окна"),
                    _T("ERROR"),
                    MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        return false;
    }

    static PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd=
    {
        sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR),
        1,
        PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL |PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER, 
        PFD_TYPE_RGBA,
        bits,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 
        32,
        0,
        0,
        PFD_MAIN_PLANE,
        0,
        0, 0, 0
    };

    if(!(hDC = GetDC(hWnd)))
    {
        KillGLWindow();
        MessageBox(NULL,
                    _T("Невозможно получить контекст устройства"),
                    _T("ERROR"),
                    MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return false;
    }

    if(!(PixelFormat = ChoosePixelFormat(hDC, &pfd)))
    {
        KillGLWindow();
        MessageBox(NULL,
                    _T("Невозможно установить формат пикселя"),
                    _T("ERROR"),
                    MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return false;
    }

    if(!wglMakeCurrent(hDC, hRC))
    {
        KillGLWindow();
        MessageBox(NULL,
                    _T("Невозможно активировать конетекст рендеринга"),
                    _T("ERROR"),
                    MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return false;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    SetFocus(hWnd);
    ReSizeGLScene(width, height);

    if(!InitGL())
    {
        KillGLWindow();
        MessageBox(NULL,
                    _T("Ошибка инициализации окна"),
                    _T("ERROR"),
                    MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc( HWND hWNd,
                            UINT uMsg,
                            WPARAM wParam,
                            LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(uMsg)
    {
        case WM_ACTIVATE:
        {
            if(!HIWORD(wParam))
            {
                active = true;
            }
            else 
            {
                active = false;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
        {
            switch(wParam)
            {
                case SC_SCREENSAVE:
                case SC_MONITORPOWER:
                return 0;
            }
            break;
        }

        case WM_CLOSE:
        {
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;
        }
        case WM_KEYUP:
        {
            keys[wParam] = false;
            return 0;
        }

        case WM_SIZE:
        {
            ReSizeGLScene( LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam) ); 
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return(DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg,wParam, lParam));
}

int WINAPI WinMain( HINSTANCE hInstance,
                    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
                    int nCmdShow )
{
    MSG msg;
    BOOL done = false;
    if(MessageBox(NULL, 
                _T("Хотите ли Вы запустить приложение в полноэкранном режиме?"),
                _T("Запустить в полноэкранном режиме?"),
                MB_YESNO | MB_ICONQUESTION) == IDNO )
    {
        fullscreen = false;
    }

    if(!CreateGLWindow(_T("OpenGL окно"), 1024, 768, 32, fullscreen))
    {
        return 0;
    }

    while(!done)
    {
        if(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if(msg.message = WM_QUIT)
            {
                done = true;
            }
        else
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
        }
        else
        {
            if(active)
            {
                if(keys[VK_ESCAPE])
                {
                    done = true;
                }
                else {
                    DrawGLScene();
                    SwapBuffers(hDC);
                }
            }
                  if( keys[VK_F1] )         
                  {
                    keys[VK_F1] = false;       
                    KillGLWindow();      
                    fullscreen = !fullscreen;      

                    if( !CreateGLWindow( _T("NeHe OpenGL структура"), 1024, 768, 32, fullscreen ) )
                    {
                      return 0;       
                    }
                }
        }

    }
    KillGLWindow();               
    return ( msg.wParam );             
}
```

При запуске данного кода в MSVC++ вылетает ошибка "Ошибка при создании окна". Т.е., как я понимаю ошибка CreateWindowEx возвращает false. Пытался найти проблему, не нашёл. Помогите пожалуйста. В чем здесь ошибка?

Comment: До боли знакомый код )

Comment: И зачем надо было копировать сюда весь код? Достаточно было показатьGLWindow и его вызов.

Comment: Используя glew или SDL всё можно делать проще понятнее и красивые. если хотите могу показать пример с glew библиотекой заточеной для создания окон OpenGL.